# Javascript MVC: model method called inside controller returns udefined -> but why?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have been learning javascript and I tried to use MVC. I noticed a problem and I could not find the answer to why, anywhere. The problem is following:

I have a class Model as follows in `model.js`:

```
export default class Model {
    constructor() {}

    speak(word) {
        return word;
    }
}
```

and controller (`controller.js`):

```
import Model from './model.js';

export default class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.model = new Model();
    }

    speak(word) {
        this.model.speak(word);
    }
}
```

I am only explicitly writing export and import here, since I have it this way in my app and I want this example code to mimic my problem as much as possible. I have separate files for each class or component. Anyway, later, in my main AppController, I have

```
import Controller from './controller.js';

const controller = new Controller();
console.log(controller.speak('Hi'));
```

The last line always returns `undefined`, no matter what I return, whether it is, as in this case, a simple string, or any attribute of model class. I know, when I do this:

```
controller.model.speak('Hi');
```

Then everything is OK.
My question therefore is not how to solve it, but why is that happening?
Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `Controller.speak` return a value.

```
speak(word) {
    return this.model.speak(word);
}
```

Comment: Oh, of course! Such a stupid mistake! Thank you very much! And I though the problem is much deeper...

Answer (score 1):

You have not returned a result from the controller speak() function.

Answer (score 0):

`controller.model.speak('Hi')` instead of this if you write `console.log(controller.model.speak('Hi'));` you will see that `Hi`.

Comment: hi, yeah, I know, I only didn`t write that console.log in my question becouse I thought it was clear from the context.. sorry for that omission, my mistake.. thanks for answer, anyway